# Windows 8 "Choose an option" screen -- when in the boot process does it come up? What DLLs does it use?

Tags: boot, windows-8-preview

What kind of a program is the Windows 8 "Choose an Option" page?

i.e.:

- Which `.exe` file (if any) corresponds to this program?
- Does it run as a user-mode component or a kernel-mode component?
- Is it a native NT executable, or does it run under the Win32 subsystem?
- Does it come up before or after turning on paging?

[image: Boot options menu]

Comment: why would you want to know thin, im just interested....

Comment: @TaylorGibb: Trying to understand how the boot process works/how it has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it... it seems to be `bootux.dll`.

It's executing in user-mode indeed -- it's written in C++ and it's using DUI70.dll (the internal DirectUI API), along with other Win32 components.